# Selenium with Python hangs on the next line of code after logging into a website

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have been experimenting with automating some tasks with Selenium, and was able to get it to work successfully once, however, when I try and recreate what I did to write it into a class, with both headless and the browser open, I run into an issue where it either hangs after logging in (with the browser open) or the login will fail due to incorrect password when headless (same info that is used when the browser is open and logs in successfully).

When using default settings (Chromedriver), I can navigate to the login page, populate my info, hit the submit button, the webpage acts as it should, but the next line of code I run, no matter what (get_cookies, any kind of find call, get_screenshot_as_file), it will hang up, and timeout if I have the timeout setting applied, if not applied, I have let it run for 5 minutes with nothing happening.

When applying the headless option to the driver (desired functionality), through screenshots of the webpage, I am able to see that it is navigating to the page and populating all of the info properly, however it will always say login failed due to incorrect user/password when submitting, but it is the exact info used in the above when it logged in just fine (could this be cookie related? Not sure what all changes when headless is applied).

I have restarted my computer, updated all packages, restarted the text editor (Atom running Hydrogen), updated Chrome, uninstalled Chrome, did every combination of option I could think of, and I am still unable to recreate my first run where it worked just fine.

Versions:
* Mac OSX Catalina 10.15
* Python: 3.6.8
* Selenium: 3.141.0
* Chrome: 80.0.3987.163

-Current Code EDIT (My text editor is setup to run like a Jupyter notebook for reference, and I listed out all of the options I have attempted, not all are included in each run I have tried)-

```
LOGIN = os.environ.get['BANKUSER']
PASSWORD = os.environ.get['BANKPASS']
chrme_drvr = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google 
Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" 

options.add_argument("--window-size=300,150")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--webdriver-logfile=webdrive.log")
options.add_argument("--DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null ")

service_args = []
service_log_path = './chromedriver.log'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrme_drvr,
                       options=options,
                       service_args=service_args,
                       service_log_path=service_log_path)

login_url = 'https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/nn/login/login.html&lang=en'
driver.get(login_url)
driver.switch_to.frame('loginIframe')
username = driver.find_element_by_id('LoginId')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('Password')
username.send_keys(LOGIN)
password.send_keys(PASSWORD)
driver.find_element_by_id('LoginSubmitBtn').click() #Code works through this line when not in headless mode, will be an invalid login when in headless mode

driver.get_screenshot_as_file("test.png") # This hangs

driver.get_cookies() # This hangs

element = browser.find_element_by_id("accounts_summary") # This hangs
```

``

Comment: Hi Kyle. Please show some of the "offending" code right at the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for omitting that, definitely important, I have updated to include the current code, and commented next to the lines that I am running into issues with

Comment: No problem. Good job, Kyle. To me as a reader, code is the first thing i look for.